# My Bibliography is Empty!! Latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I don't know why it only displays the first 2 options in the references part!! Please help
I have included the .bib file in the main file. I tried to use the .bbl file, but it is very time wasting and it also didn't work! it gave me [?] in the pdf file instead of numbering the references after they already appear.
HELP

the .bib file:

```
@misc{citeKey1,
  title={{http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/shaders/}},
  author={html5rocks},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Paul Lewis}
}
@misc{citeKey2,
title={{http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp}},
author={w3schools}
}

@misc{citeKey3,
title={{http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Draw_Circle_Pixel.html}},
author={Kathir Software}
}

@misc{citeKey4,
title={{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248056/how-to-create-a-treemap-webgl/21274180?noredirect=1#21274180}},
author={stackoverflow},
year={2013},
publisher={gman}
}

@misc{citeKey5,
title={{http://wikipedia.org}},
author={Wikipedia The Free Encyclopedia}
}
@misc{citeKey6,
Author = {Elias, Rimon},
Institution = {German University in Cairo},
Howpublished = {University Lecture},
Year = {2010},
Title = {Visualization and Animation DMET702}
}
```

and the main.tex file:

```
% add more chapters here
\include{Implementation}
\include{conclusion}
\include{future_work}
\include{appendix}


\bibliography{bachelor}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

Comment: did you run `bibtex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Sounds like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number?rq=1 to me